# Eventbrite API - OAuth Setup - Correct URL?

Tags: php, laravel, openid-connect, eventbrite

I'm following the Eventbrite OAuth docs here:

https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/introduction/authentication

The docs say to "redirect" a user to this URL:
https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_API_KEY&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI

So I created a link on a page to this URL, replacing "YOUR_API_KEY" with my API key and "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI" with the URL for my local devsite url that will handle the user's access code when it comes back.

When I click the link I reach a page at eventbrite.com that says:

"The application you're trying to use has made an invalid request to Eventbrite. Please contact the application developer."

No error code or anything for me as the developer.

I am writing this app in Laravel/PHP, and all of their code examples use curl which I am not familiar with.

I appreciate your thoughts/ideas.

Comment: Show us how you do what you do. In other word, show us you code

Comment: This is OpenID Connect. Most likely, they required the `redirect_uri` to be both over **HTTPS** and to an **FQDN** (i.e. not `localhost` or ip address). That's standard security practice. Simple solution: use `ngrok`. Complex solution: see if they have a developer mode flag somewhere that allows hacky `redirect_uri`.

Comment: Their example URI is http://localhost:8080/oauth/redirect?code=YOUR_ACCESS_CODE, which uses http, not https, and is on a localhost, so I don't think https is required.